# Change other user's mouse sensitivity through rdp

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, mouse

At my company we have some "*public computers*" (accessible for everyone who passes by) on the workfloor. Those computers run in some kind of kiosk mode due to security reasons.

They connect to a virtual Windows 7 desktop through VMware Horizon Client. The desktop has been stripped off so people can only use 2 applications and logout. This means they can't access the control panel etc themselves to adjust the mouse sensitivity.

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to change the mouse sensitivity for another user on the desktop?

**EDIT:** I only want to change the mouse cursor speed of a user on a specific desktop.

Comment: Create a registry setting as a bat or powershell script, and run as a logon script. The registry path is:`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`, and find `MouseSpeed`, change the value as you want. then use the group policy to set it as a startup script for the RDP users.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. Will that script change the cursor speed for that user on all desktops in the company or only a specific desktop? (I've edited the question to make it more clear.)